# L1 Norm regression

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

First time poster...apologies for formatting.

I am trying to devise a solution to a familiar linear algebra equation, **A***x*=*b*, where all elements in **A** are non-negative and all the elements in *b* are positive. My constraint is that the difference between the L1 norm of **A***x* and L1 norm of *b* must be minimized (ie min (||**A***x*||_1 - ||*b*||_1)). In english, I want the coefficients that make the sum of the elements in *b* "closest" to the sum of the elements in **A***x*.

Hoping to find out whether there is an algorithmic solution to this problem, preferably in Python.

Comment: Are you sure that is the objective?  If it is, an optimal solution is $x=0$.  If you meant to minimize $\left|\|Ax\|_1 - \|b\|_1\right|$, just take any $y$ with $Ay \ne 0$ and let $x = \dfrac{\|b\|_1}{\|Ay\|_1 }y$ to make the objective value $0$.  Or did you mean to minimize $\|Ax - b \|_1$?

Comment: Thanks @RobertIsrael. I do want \begin{equation} |||Ax||_1 - ||b||_1|_1
\end{equation}. (the other would be l1 regression). The solution you proposed gives x as a scalar, correct? x is a vector, though. Rusty in my linear algebra, been quite a few years. Much appreciate the help

Comment: For more context...Suppose I'm in retail and I sell a number of SKUs that are oftentimes sold together. Each x is the cost of an individual SKU, but is unknown because of said bundling. The costs are a function of what's in A (which has M buyers of N SKUs), and b is the total dollars for each of my buyers. I want to find the average cost for each SKU.

Comment: No, $x$ is a vector, as is $y$.  $y$ is any vector such that $Ay \ne 0$.  Then you scale $y$, i.e. multiply it by a scalar, chosen to make $\|Ax\|_1$ equal to  $\|b\|_1$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Perhaps what you mean is that for given $A$ and $b$, you want to find some $x$, such that $\|Ax-b\|_1$ becomes minimal?

Comment: @RobertIsrael provided the correct answer. And there is no unique solution to the problem as stated. Will need to reformulate more carefully based on the use case: Suppose I'm in retail and I sell a number of SKUs that are oftentimes sold together. Each x is the cost of an individual SKU, but is unknown because of said bundling. The costs are a function of what's in A (which has M buyers of N SKUs), and b is the total dollars for each of my buyers. I want to find the average cost for each SKU.